# How to connect Remote Sql Server using PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I want to connect to SQL Server 2008 from my local machine.

I have completed the driver installation from this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx)

But this extension does not support remote connection to Sql Server. It has to be installed on same machine where PHP is installed. ( got from [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php) )

How should I resolve above issue?

Is there any alternative solution for it?

Comment: Did you read the error? It tells you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @Mark B  - I know it asks me to install Sql Server on same machine but I don't want to do that. I want to connect to SQL Server which is on remote machine

Comment: I have edited my question and removed code and error I think is not necessary here.

Comment: you don't have to install the entire thing, just the client. it's an option during isntall

Comment: @Mark B - Thanks, It worked !!. I am new in Sql Server/PHP I thought I had to install whole thing so I was looking for some other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PHP extensions required installed SQL **client** not server.

Client allow you connect to any servers and remote too. PHP extension use library from this client distr.